# Stock cutting and column generation giving suboptimal answers?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, optimization, linear-programming

I'm doing a stock cutting implementation. I use the delayed column generation approach.

I'm getting suboptimal answers with the following simple case:

> raws length: 630 in.
>
> demands:
>
> 10 x 19 in.
>
> 10 x 22 in.
>
> 10 x 16 in.

The expected solution is: use 1 raw.

My implementation gives: use 3 raws.

From what I have debugged:

- The subproblem (column generation) is not generating the optimal global pattern for the master problem.
- The subproblem generates patterns that are not useful like: [37 x 16in, 2 x 19in] = 630in
- The suboptimal patterns always seem to reduce cost in the subproblem better than the right answer [10 x 16in, 10 x 19in, 10 x 22in]

Furthermore:

- I have downloaded other open source implementations and they have the same problems as mine.
- My implementation has tests and I have reproduced scientific articles that show the iterations step by step checking that the duals and columns produced are correct at each iteration.

Possibilities:

- Does the column generation approach give local optima answers? My impression from the current literature is that it always finds the global optima but I might be wrong.
- Some missing step (which apparently most open source implementations are missing as well).

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

/* Objective function */

max: +C1 +C2 +C3;

/* Constraints */

+19 C1 +22 C2 +16 C3 <= 630;

/* Add RHS */

+C1 <= 10;
+C2 <= 10;
+C3 <= 10;

/* Integer definitions */

int C1,C2,C3;